# Add vite to an existing html javascript application

Tags: svelte, vite

I have been trying to add vite to an existing project in the past 48h and I couldn't do it and I did not understand what I'm doing wrong, so here it is my files path.

[image]

here it is `uisource` folder expanded:
[image]

Now the `vite.config.js file`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
     root: 'uisource',
     build: {
          outDir: '../dist',
     },
});
```

when i run the command `npm run build`it creates a folder dist with this files:

[image]

[image]

Now when i run the `dist`app it doesn't work at all

[image]

And I'm getting those errors as well

```
index.html:7 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index-6N88Un27.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index-pB-xsafd.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
index.html:37 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/eye-JCKRoSr5.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

here it is the `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/fonts/webfonts/all.css" />
          <title>HorusEye</title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div id="container">
               <div id="canvasContiner">
                    <div id="gamePanel">
                         <div id="crossBar"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark myIcons"></i></div>
                         <div id="dashIcon"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus myIcons"></i></div>
                         <div id="securityCameraIcon">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-video myIcons"></i>
                         </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="canvas">
                         <canvas></canvas>
                    </div>

                    <div id="progressBar">
                         <div id="countingBar"></div>
                         <span id="counterMessage">Fast Fast!</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="userInputContainer">
                         <div id="firstPassword">
                              <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter the password" />
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
          <img src="./images/eye.svg" />
     </body>
     <script type="module" src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong!